# Making a dynamic, interactive function

Tags: elisp-macros, defun

I have make a macro that creates dynamic functions:

```
(defmacro tjb-make-register-macro (func-name out-string)
   (list 'defun func-name () '(interactive) (list 'insert out-string)))

;; This call succeeds [note abc1 is not defined]:
(tjb-make-register-macro abc1 "hello1")

;; These fail:
(tjb-make-register-macro (make-symbol "abc2") "hello2")
(tjb-make-register-macro (intern "abc2") "hello2")

;; I'm trying to write a function like this to call this macro dynamically
;; but this doesn't work:
(defun tjb-make-register (func-name out-string)
  (interactive "sFunc-name:\nsfunc-out")
  (tjb-make-register-macro ((intern func-name) out-string)))
```

How can I make an interactive function that correctly calls my macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to avoid the defun macro and use defalias for setting up the function:

```
  (defalias (intern "tjb-make-register")
      (lambda (func-name out-string)
        (interactive "sFunc-name:\nsfunc-out\n")
        (fset (intern func-name) (eval `(lambda () (interactive) (insert ,out-s\
tring))))))
```

Comment: I'd suggest `defalias` instead of `fset`

Comment: Not sure how to make that work here, can you provide an example?

Comment: Just write `defalias` where you currently have `fset`.